# how do I select first p tag from html that is a string?

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I'm fetching content from a headless CMS and I get content as a string like:

```
<div>
  <p>1st p tag</p>
  <p>2nd p tag</p>
</div>
```

how do I select the 1st p tag so I can have something like this:

```
const firstPtagContent = "1st p tag"
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('p')` would select the first `p` ... and `.textContent` would be its text content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse the string using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and use `querySelector` to get the first `p`

```js
const str = `<div>
  <p>1st p tag</p>
  <p>2nd p tag</p>
</div>`

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html')

console.log(
  doc.querySelector('p').textContent
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```js
var firstParagraph = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
console.log(firstParagraph.textContent)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>1st p element</p>
  <p>2st p element</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below snippet.

```js
var firstParagraph = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
console.log(firstParagraph.textContent)
```

```css
p { outline: dotted  red } /* Just to show the widths */
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <p>1st p tag</p>
   <p>2nd p tag</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try something like this:

```js
const str = `<div>
  <p>1st p tag</p>
  <p>2nd p tag</p>
</div>`

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html')

console.log(
  doc.querySelector('p').textContent
)
```